# Parsing a JSON File with same properties but different "Names"

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm new to JSON and can't wrap my head around the following problem:

I'm getting a JSON file from a third party program. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"Name 1": {
    "Property 1": 154600,
    "Property 2": true,
    "Property 3": 5340,
    "Property 4": 54634
  },
  "Name 2": {
    "Property 1": 5436,
    "Property 2": false,
    "Property 3": 45678769,
    "Property 4": 2342342
  }
}
```

I need to get them in a Listview with a column for every Property and the Name.

I generated a class with the JSONUtils website:

```
    Public Class Name1

        <JsonProperty("Property 1")>
        Public Property Property1 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 2")>
        Public Property Property2 As Boolean

        <JsonProperty("Property 3")>
        Public Property Property3 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 4")>
        Public Property Property4 As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Name2

        <JsonProperty("Property 1")>
        Public Property Property1 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 2")>
        Public Property Property2 As Boolean

        <JsonProperty("Property 3")>
        Public Property Property3 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 4")>
        Public Property Property4 As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class NameList

        <JsonProperty("Name 1")>
        Public Property Name1 As Name1

        <JsonProperty("Name 2")>
        Public Property Name2 As Name2
    End Class
```

But because of the changing Names I would have to dynamically add those classes on runtime.

Next I tried to generate a class which looks like this:

```
    Public Class NameList

        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("Property 1")>
        Public Property Property1 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 2")>
        Public Property Property2 As Boolean

        <JsonProperty("Property 3")>
        Public Property Property3 As Integer

        <JsonProperty("Property 4")>
        Public Property Property4 As Integer
    End Class
```

That would be as intended, but when i run the testprogram, I'm getting an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Below my code:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim stream As Stream = client.OpenRead("C:\\Filename.json")
Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream)
Dim jsonData As String = reader.ReadToEnd

reader.Close()

Dim allData As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData)

Dim nameDataList As New List(Of NameList)

For Each token As JToken In allData("")

      Dim prop As JProperty = token

      If Not prop.Name.StartsWith("_") Then
          nameDataList.Add(New NameList With {
              .Name = prop.Name,
              .Property1 = prop.Value("Property 1"),
              .Property2 = prop.Value("Property 2"),
              .Property3 = prop.Value("Property 3"),
              .Property4 = prop.Value("Property 4")})
      End If

Next
```

After that comes the code to add the token to my Listview.

The Error occours on this line:

```
For Each token As JToken In allData("")
```

How can i avoid this error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can deserialize that JSON (for example) as a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String)))` (where all the properties values are represented as strings) or as a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Dynamic)))` (where all the properties values are *dynamically* evaluated at run-time). It should be simple to manage, if you need to add each object (`"Name 1"`, `"Name 2"` or whatever these keys will be named) to a ListView.

Comment: Okay, sounds good... now i have to look into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allData("") does not have any JTokens. Its a KeyValuePair of [string, JToken].

Try removing the ("") from your code, and the As JToken. Like so:

```vb
    For Each obj As KeyValuePair In allData
        Dim name As String = obj.Key
        Dim token As JToken = obj.Value
    Next
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4ZED9z