# Convert json formatted data to c# classes with weird array

Tags: c#, json

```
"items": [
    {
        "product": "desktop-licence",
        "quantity": 1,
        "display": "Desktop Licence",
        "sku": "DTQ-P",
        "subtotal": 46.32,
        "subtotalDisplay": "$46.32 AUD",
        "subtotalInPayoutCurrency": 30.08,
        "subtotalInPayoutCurrencyDisplay": "USD 30.08",
        "discount": 0.0,
        "discountDisplay": "$0.00 AUD",
        "discountInPayoutCurrency": 0.0,
        "discountInPayoutCurrencyDisplay": "USD 0.00",
        "fulfillments": {
            "desktop-licence_license_0": [
                {
                    "license": "\"BHFU-FK95-SQLF-JCG7-9NAY-969H-98\"",
                    "display": "License Key",
                    "type": "license"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The above is an extract from a response received from my reseller - Fastspring.

I'm having difficulty with having my web api convert the `fulfillments` section into a c# class. I just can't figure out how the class/classes are constructed to account for the `"desktop-licence_license_0"` line. This value can be defined by me and will vary according to the product name.

In my `Items` class I have:

```
public Fulfillment[] fulfillments {get; set;}
```

and the `Fulfillment` class has properties for all the fields in the array, i.e. `license`, `display`, `type`.

Obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Copy your json to the clipboard then **Edit Menu** -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste Json as Classes**  let Visual Studio figure it out for you

Comment: Posible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248490/parsing-a-json-file-with-same-properties-but-different-names/58248738#58248738. Same question, different json structure.

Comment: @Vincent It's the structure in json that I am having the problem with!

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp VS2019 is great ain't it. That's got me in the right direction but I don't want to make a class for each possible fulfillment. I need to get the variable string into a class - and then load it's properties into a class I have already defined.

Comment: @David, i adjusted my answer and provided a working example of how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq package and namespace to parse custom named json objects.

See the question and answer in link below:

[Parsing a JSON File with same properties but different "Names"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248490/parsing-a-json-file-with-same-properties-but-different-names/58248738#58248738)

EDIT:

To be more specific and answer your question on how to parse the custom name to a c# class, here is a working example of how to do this (using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq).

I used a string customAttrName = "fulfillmentItem" where you can define your custom attribute name as string value.

The important part is getting the name dynamicly from the json itself:

```cs
// Custom name.
string customAttrName = "";

foreach (JObject obj in jsonObj["items"])
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> token in obj)
    {
        if (token.Key == "fulfillments")
        {
            JObject jobj = (JObject) token.Value;
            customAttrName = (jobj.Properties().Select( p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Once we have this name we can parse it to c# classes.

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nu254O

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("{");
        sb.Append("   \"items\": [");
        sb.Append("        {");
        sb.Append("            \"product\": \"desktop-licence\",");
        sb.Append("            \"quantity\": 1,");
        sb.Append("            \"display\": \"Desktop Licence\",");
        sb.Append("            \"sku\": \"DTQ-P\",");
        sb.Append("            \"subtotal\": 46.32,");
        sb.Append("            \"subtotalDisplay\": \"$46.32 AUD\",");
        sb.Append("            \"subtotalInPayoutCurrency\": 30.08,");
        sb.Append("            \"subtotalInPayoutCurrencyDisplay\": \"USD 30.08\",");
        sb.Append("            \"discount\": 0.0,");
        sb.Append("            \"discountDisplay\": \"$0.00 AUD\",");
        sb.Append("            \"discountInPayoutCurrency\": 0.0,");
        sb.Append("            \"discountInPayoutCurrencyDisplay\": \"USD 0.00\",");
        sb.Append("            \"fulfillments\": {");
        sb.Append("            \"fulfillmentItem\": [");
        sb.Append("                {");
        sb.Append("                \"license\": \"\\\"BHFU-FK95-SQLF-JCG7-9NAY-969H-98\\\"\",");
        sb.Append("                \"display\": \"License Key\",");
        sb.Append("                \"type\": \"license\"");
        sb.Append("                }");
        sb.Append("           ]");
        sb.Append("      }");
        sb.Append("  }");
        sb.Append(" ]");
        sb.Append("}");

        // Parse normal properties.
        var oItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(sb.ToString());

        // Parse custom fufillments array.
        var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(sb.ToString());

        // Custom name.
        string customAttrName = "";

        foreach (JObject obj in jsonObj["items"])
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> token in obj)
            {
                if (token.Key == "fulfillments")
                {
                    JObject jobj = (JObject) token.Value;
                    customAttrName = (jobj.Properties().Select( p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
        }

        // Init.
        oItem.fulfillments = new Fulfillments();
        oItem.fulfillments.fulfillmentItem = new List<FulfillmentItem>();

        // Get data using JToken. << use some for loop if multiple fulfillments...
        string licence = (string)jsonObj.SelectToken("items[0].fulfillments." + customAttrName + "[0].license");
        string display = (string)jsonObj.SelectToken("items[0].fulfillments." + customAttrName + "[0].display");
        string type = (string)jsonObj.SelectToken("items[0].fulfillments." + customAttrName + "[0].type");

        oItem.fulfillments.fulfillmentItem.Add(new FulfillmentItem() {
            license = licence,
            display = display,
            type = type
        });

        // Check values.
        foreach (var itm in oItem.fulfillments.fulfillmentItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itm.license);
            Console.WriteLine(itm.display);
        }

        // return oItem;
    }
}


public partial class Item
{
    public string product { get; set; }
    public long quantity { get; set; }
    public string sisplay { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public double subtotal { get; set; }
    public string subtotalDisplay { get; set; }
    public double subtotalInPayoutCurrency { get; set; }
    public string subtotalInPayoutCurrencyDisplay { get; set; }
    public long discount { get; set; }
    public string discountDisplay { get; set; }
    public long discountInPayoutCurrency { get; set; }
    public string discountInPayoutCurrencyDisplay { get; set; }
    public Fulfillments fulfillments { get; set; }
}

public partial class Fulfillments
{
    public List<FulfillmentItem> fulfillmentItem { get; set; }
}

public partial class FulfillmentItem
{
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string display { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no real answer here unfortunately, and a  comment would have been more fitting

Comment: @TheGeneral. True: could elaborate more. Edited the post to include a real answer.